# Detected request JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm currently writing a JSP-application with webservices. The problem is: I should detect the clicked link so I can redirect to the specific jsp page. On this JSP-page there will be a request to the web service which will be also done by the same servlet. (Or is it easier to create two different servlets?)

Does anyone have a solution/suggestion to detect the clicked link in JSP? Or do I have to store this in the session?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like a job for JavaScript. Normally, the link you click will be handled by the browser - your JEE app doesn't get involved unless the link points to a JSP or Servlet.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you want to do? It sounds like you want to have two different links which go to two different pages. Which you do by making the hrefs of the links point to those different pages. Do you mean something different?

Comment: In order to communicate with my webservice I have to put that reference in the servlet. So when I click on a specific link I want to go to that specific page and when I then execute that action I want that the servlet take care of that action...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your request is a `HttpServletRequest` you could call `getRequestURI()` or `getRequestURL()`.